# Elasticsearch get all results as substring PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am creating a search query using **ELASTIC SEARCH** in `PHP` to search names just like the `LIKE` query of `SQL`and I want to fetch all the names from my records where any substring matches.

For example, the name is: **"SOME NAME"** which I want to search from my records and my sample records are like following which all are required to be searched. All searches are case-insensitive.

```
--> SOME NAME
--> NAME Jhon
--> SOME myname
--> SOME NAMES IN A STRING
--> The NAME of the some
--> MYNAME is
```

Above all example strings are all have some substring of the given string of user.

Below strings are not required.

```
--> The string is a dummy string
--> no string is here which the  user entered
```

Here's my mapping: Note that `name_description` is just for searching in multiplied, but the focus is only on name field.

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/myindex/_mymapping/list" -d '{
        "list" : {
          "properties" : {
            "name" : {
              "type": "multi_field",
              "fields": {
                  "name": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                          },
                  "name_description": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                          }
              }
            }
          }
        }
}'; echo
```

And my php code:

```
$my_config = $this->getDI()->get('config');
$elasticsearch_client= new Elasticsearch\Client();
$my_params['index'] = "myindex";
$my_params['type']  = "list";
$my_query["match"]["name"] = array(
    "query"=> "SOME NAME",
    "operator" => "and"
);
$my_params["body"]["query"]["filtered"] = array(
    "query"=>$my_query
);
$res = $elasticsearch_client->search($my_params);
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: First off, just to make sure, in your mapping creation `/myindex/_mymapping/list` should read `/myindex/_mapping/list`, i.e. there is no `_mymapping` endpoint in ES. Do you confirm you're using `_mapping` and not `_mymapping`?

Comment: @Val yes you are correct, mistakenly I did that. It is _mapping.

Comment: Did it solve anything or did you just made that typo while writing the question?

Comment: I just made typo while publishing this question.